# Piping echo output into xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm trying to pipe a list of values through `xargs`. Here's a simple example:

```
echo "Hello Hola Bonjour" | xargs -I _ echo _ Landon
```

I would expect this to output the following:

```
Hello Landon
Hola Landon
Bonjour Landon
```

Instead, the command outputs this:

```
Hello Hola Bonjour Landon
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You wouldn't have this issue with `echo "Hello Hola Bonjour" | xargs printf '%s Landon\n'` (since `printf` reuses its format string when it sees extra arguments, `printf '%s Landon\n' Hello Hola Bonjour` will print the three lines you expect). In general, `xargs -I` is best avoided; it has serious (security) issues when applied to common use cases (like substituting into `sh -c '...'` strings).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under `-I`, `man xargs` says

> unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the
>                 separator is the newline character

You can specify a different delimiter (at least in GNU xargs):

```
printf 'Hello Hola Bonjour' | xargs -d' ' -I _ echo _ Landon
```

More portably, use `\0` as the delimiter and `-0` to use it:

```
printf '%s\0' Hello Hola Bonjour | xargs -0 -I _ echo _ Landon
```

Comment: Any suggestions on macOS? The `-d` flag isn't available.

Comment: @LandonSchropp ...generally, the best practice is to use NUL delimiters, not spaces *or* newlines: `printf '%s\0' Hello Hola Bonjour | xargs -0 -I _ echo _ Landon`. NUL is the only character that can't exist in a C string (a filename, etc), so it's the only thing that's guaranteed to be safe to use to separate arbitrary strings; and `xargs -0` is available on MacOS.

Comment: @LandonSchropp Mac has BSD tools that are largely non-portable. You can install the more portable GNU version which `brew install findutils`. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/467284) has some additional details.

Answer (score 4):

The delimiter needs to be changed, and you also have to specify the -L option.  So either change the delimiter via -d like the other answer suggested, or pipe to sed and replace space with linefeed

```
echo "Hello Hola Bonjour" | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | xargs -L 1 -I _ echo _ Landon
```

Results in

```
Hello Landon
Hola Landon
Bonjour Landon
```

Sometimes changing the delimiters is not enough.  xargs will sometimes take all the input arguments and pass it all at once.  There is no splitting of the arguments.

e.g.

```
seq 1 7 | xargs echo
```

results in

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

being passed to xargs, so the output would be

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If you add a -L 1 shown in the xargs man page

> -L max-lines
>                 Use  at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line to be
>                 logically continued on the next input line.  Implies -x.

```
seq 1 7 | xargs -L 1 echo
```

then you will see

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

You can also covert it manually to a for loop which lets you setup multi line statements more easily.

```
# be absolutely sure the values the for loop iterates over is well sanitized to avoid glob expansion of the *.
for i in Hello Hola Bonjour
do
  if [ "$i" = "Hello" ]
  then
    echo "$i Landon, language detected as English!"
  else
    echo "$i Landon, language detected as non English."
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The -I flag changes the delimiter to newline.

> Unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.

You can read about it [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

You have to manually specify the delimiter to be a space. Echo also inserts a newline by default, which messes up xargs. Use the -n flag to remove the newline.

Here is the fixed command:

```
echo -n "Hello Hola Bonjour" | xargs -d' ' -I _ echo _ Landon
```